# How to deal with batch normalization for multiple datasets?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am working on a task of generating synthetic data to help the training of my model. This means that the training is performed on synthetic + real data, and tested on real data.

I was told that batch normalization layers might be trying to find weights that are good for all while training, which is a problem since the distribution of my synthetic data is not exactly equal to the distribution of the real data. So, the idea would be to have different ‘copies’ of the weights of batch normalization layers. So that the neural network estimates different weights for synthetic and real data, and uses just the weights of real data for evaluation.

Could someone suggest me good ways to actually implement that in pytorch? My idea was the following, after each epoch of training in a dataset I would go through all batchnorm layers and save their weights. Then at the beginning of the next epoch I would iterate again loading the right weights. Is this a good approach? Still, I am not sure how I should deal with the batch-norm weights at test time since batch-norm treats it differently.

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of implementation?

Comment: I just tried something else. When building the model I create copies of the batchnorm layers for each training dataset. Then I pass the dataset name to the Forward function, and there i select the right layers at each run. 
However I am not sure if this is a good procedure and will work

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem you're worried about is that your neural network will learn weights that work well when the batch norm is computed for a batch of both real and synthetic data, and then later at test time it will compute a batch norm on just real data?

Rather than trying to track multiple batch norms, you probably just want to set `track_running_stats` to `True` for your batch norm layer, and then put it into eval mode when testing.  This will cause it to compute a running mean and variance over multiple batches while training, and then it will use that mean and variance later at test time, rather than looking at the batch stats for the test batches.

(This is often what you want anyway, because depending on your use case, you might be sending very small batches to the deployed model, and so you want to use a pre-computed mean and variance rather than relying on stats for those small batches.)

If you really want to be computing fresh means and variances at test time, what I would do is instead of passing a single batch with both real and synthetic data into your network, I'd pass in one batch of real data, then one batch of synthetic data, and average the two losses together before backprop.  (Note that if you do this you **should not** rely on the running mean and variance later -- you'll have to either set `track_running_stats` to `False`, or reset it when you're done and run through a few dummy batches with only real data to compute reasonable values.  This is because the running mean and variance stats are only useful if they're expected to be roughly the same for every batch, and you're instead polarizing the values by feeding in different types of data in different batches.)